# Semantic release - include in CHANGELOG the commit subject, body and footer

Tags: commit, changelog, semantic-release, release-notes, conventional-changelog

I am trying to configure **semantic release** to include the *subject*, *body* and *footer* of the commit messages in `CHANGELOG.md` file, not just the subject of commit message, but no success. In my changelog I still have only the short subject of commit messages. Is there a way to set the semantic-release at this way?

Any suggestions will be helpful for me.

Answer (score 1):

This can be done, but it's not exactly straightforward. The key is to set `writerOpts` for the `@semantic-release/release-notes-generator` plugin.

In the following example `release.config.js` file which is used to configure semantic-release, I'm setting two options: `preset` (you can use a different preset) and `writerOpts` (the important parts).

```js
import { readFileSync } from 'node:fs'

const commitPartial = readFileSync('./changelog-template-commit.hbs', { encoding: 'utf-8' })

function finalizeContext (context) {
    for (const commitGroup of context.commitGroups) {
        for (const commit of commitGroup.commits) {
            commit.bodyLines = commit.body?.split('\n').filter((line) => line !== '') ?? []
        }
    }

    return context
}

export default {
    plugins: [
        '@semantic-release/commit-analyzer',
        ['@semantic-release/release-notes-generator', {
            preset: 'conventionalcommits',
            writerOpts: {
                commitPartial,
                finalizeContext,
            },
        }],
        '@semantic-release/changelog',
    ],
}
```

First, let's look at `writerOpts.commitPartial`. I'm loading a modified template that I've stored in the `changelog-template-commit.hbs` file:

```
{{!--
  Copy of https://github.com/conventional-changelog/conventional-changelog/blob/master/packages/conventional-changelog-conventionalcommits/templates/commit.hbs

  The following have been replaced:

  - `commitUrlFormat` with `{{@root.host}}/{{@root.owner}}/{{@root.repository}}/commit/{{hash}})`
  - `issueUrlFormat` with `{{@root.host}}/{{@root.owner}}/{{@root.repository}}/issues/{{this.id}}`

  As they won't be replaced when overriding the commitPartial
--}}
*{{#if scope}} **{{scope}}:**
{{~/if}} {{#if subject}}
  {{~subject}}
{{~else}}
  {{~header}}
{{~/if}}

{{~!-- commit link --}}{{~#if hash}} {{#if @root.linkReferences~}}
  ([{{shortHash}}]({{@root.host}}/{{@root.owner}}/{{@root.repository}}/commit/{{hash}}))
{{~else}}
  {{~shortHash}}
{{~/if}}{{~/if}}

{{~!-- commit references --}}
{{~#if references~}}
  , closes
  {{~#each references}} {{#if @root.linkReferences~}}
    [
    {{~#if this.owner}}
      {{~this.owner}}/
    {{~/if}}
    {{~this.repository}}{{this.prefix}}{{this.issue}}]({{@root.host}}/{{@root.owner}}/{{@root.repository}}/issues/{{this.id}})
  {{~else}}
    {{~#if this.owner}}
      {{~this.owner}}/
    {{~/if}}
    {{~this.repository}}{{this.prefix}}{{this.issue}}
  {{~/if}}{{/each}}
{{~/if}}
{{!-- End of copy --}}

{{!-- Start of custom additions --}}
{{#each bodyLines}}

  {{this}}
{{/each}}{{#each notes}}
  **BREAKING CHANGE**: {{text}}
{{/each}}
```

This is a slightly modified version of the original commit template the conventionalcommits preset uses. I've commented the changes I made to it inside the file. At the bottom, you'll find the additions for adding the commit body and breaking changes notes that I made.

For this to work, the `writerOpts.finalizeContext` option in the config above is needed. It takes each commit's `body` and turns it into a line by line array. You could technically use the `body` in the template and not worry about this, but it won't be correctly indented if you have multiple body lines. This is taken care of in my version.

---

This is probably not perfect and I wish conventional-changelog (which is used by `@semantic-release/release-notes-generator`) would provide some of this functionality out of the box, but it works for me.

Note that I haven't fully considered all pieces of information that could be in a commit footer like references that might be handled different here by the plugin. You might need to make some more adjustments.

Oh, yes, and I highly recommend trying this locally first using `npx semantic-release --dryRun`.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to look up for some issue regarding this ad found out only this https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version/issues/242

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).